# The pre image of a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The question is like this

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a function. Consider sets $A \subseteq Y$ and $B \subseteq Y$. Show that $$f^{-1}(A \cap B) \subseteq f^{-1} (A) \cap f^{-1} (B)$$

which I did as follows

Let $x \in f^{-1}(A \cap B)$ $\implies$ $f(x)\in A \cap B$ $\implies$ $f(x) \in A$ and $f(x)\in B$ $\implies$ $x  \in f^{-1}(A)$ and $x  \in f^{-1}(B)$ $\implies$ $x  \in f^{-1}(A \cap B)$, hence, $f^{-1}(A \cap B) \subseteq f^{-1} (A) \cap f^{-1} (B)$.

Please correct me if anything is wrong.

The question then goes on to ask:

$$Is\ the\ converse\ of\ the\ statement\ true\ in\ general?$$

I think the converse is true, but the way the question is posed make me feel that this is not the case.

Please help me with this problem, if the converse is true, can I just prove this by changing all my implication into equivalence? Or if the converse is false, how can I find a counterexample to show that its false?

Thanks to anybody who helps.

Comment: There's a small error in your proof:
$$x  \in f^{-1}(A) \hbox{ and } x  \in f^{-1}(B) \implies x  \in f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$$

Comment: The operation that doesn't work well is function application to intersections, that is, it is not always true that $f(A \cap B) = f(A) \cap f(B)$ (take a constant function with two non-empty disjoint sets $A,B$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ x \in f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B) \iff f(x) \in A \wedge f(x) \in B \iff f(x) \in A\cap B \iff x \in f^{-1}(A\cap B)$

So the converse statement is true. You can generalize it to infinite interstections as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof looks fine to me.

As for your second question, the answer is actually yes. Preimages play very well with intersections of sets (and unions and set differences too, try proving those if you haven't already). If you want proof, well look at what you've already written! It looks likes those implications could be biconditionals...

Unfortunately, images of sets don't play as nice with those operations and in general we just get containment in one direction (which I can't recall right now).

Answer (score 0):

The converse is true:

$$x\in f^{-1}(A\cap B)\iff f(x)\in A\cap B\iff f(x)\in A\wedge f(x)\in B\iff$$$$x\in f^{-1}(A)\wedge f^{-1}(B)\iff x\in f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B)$$

Preimages are (in contrast with images) very cooperative.